Looking for a way to control individual bones AND use FK/IK when needed
I'm pretty new to Blender, about 3 months of blending, I made the donut, then I made a sports car, so now I'm starting to make and rig my own characters.
I apologize if this is easy to do, but I've tried for about a week now, and none of the solutions I've tried seemed to work.
The character and rig I am making is a snake.

The rig uses a layer of deform bones, disconnected but parented, controlled via Copy-Transform Constraint to a Layer of Target bones, disconnected and parented to a layer of control bones and Damp-tracked to the next control bone in the chain.
The control bones are all parented to each other with the spine bone at the head parented to a root bone.

I haven't had much experience with rigging before this, other than a few simple joints for doors and such, but I think I've got a pretty good understanding of the basics. I've made rigged the jaw, the eyes to a tracker I can place on a focal object for an animation, eyebrows, bone drivers for shape keys for mouth shapes, lips, eyelids, and it's all gone a lot better than I expected (largely in part to the excellent tutorials and answers found right here!).
What I am struggling with, is a simple animation to make the snake sway back and forth slightly while doing other actions.
Because the rig is set up in FK, I can't move the head side to side without needing to reposition the entire bone chain, which moves slightly throughout the animation, rather than staying still.

In addition to individual bone control, I also want to be able to use FK, as it is extremely useful for curling and bending the body quickly, and also select which part of the rig is affected by the movement, and which bones (like the bones resting on the ground) will stay perfectly still.
I tried IK controls, but wasn't able to successfully get it working (Likely not doing it correctly), but I feel like it is going to be the correct answer if I can figure it out.
The closest I came to a solution was un-parenting and disconnecting the Control chain, and using "child-of" constraints to temporarily suspend the FK-like controls after setting up a pose.
But as soon as I turned off the constraints, the entire pose was destroyed as the bones moved back to their pre-"child-of" positions.
I'm not sure what all information will be helpful, but I'm happy to add any additional information if it will help!
Thanks in advance!
